# ?posts_type=xxx not rewritten

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

After some more testing and tweaks my main problem *seems* to be the order rewrite rules are applied, and the second is canonicalization.

I'm using this in function.php makes year archives work:

```
/**
* Generate date archive rewrite rules for a given custom post type
* @param  string $cpt        slug of the custom post type
* @return rules              returns a set of rewrite rules for Wordpress to handle
*/
function my_generate_date_archives($cpt, $wp_rewrite) { 
$rules = array();

$post_type = get_post_type_object($cpt);
$slug_archive = $post_type->has_archive;
if ($slug_archive === false) return $rules;
if ($slug_archive === true) {
    $slug_archive = $post_type->name;
}

$dates = array(
    array(
        'rule' => "([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})",
        'vars' => array('year', 'monthnum', 'day')),
    array(
        'rule' => "([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})",
        'vars' => array('year', 'monthnum')),
    array(
        'rule' => "([0-9]{4})",
        'vars' => array('year'))
    ); 

foreach ($dates as $data) {
    $query = 'index.php?post_type='.$cpt;
    $rule = $slug_archive.'/'.$data['rule'];

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($data['vars'] as $var) {
        $query.= '&'.$var.'='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
        $i++;
    }

    $rules[$rule."/?$"] = $query;
    $rules[$rule."/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$"] = $query."&paged=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
}
return $rules;
}
```

If I do `http://domain.com/?post_type=publications&year=2013` the desired posts are shown, but the URL is re-written to `http://domain.com/2013/?post_type=publications`

If I do `http://domain.com/publications/2013/` the correct posts are shown.

If I do `http://domain.com/publications/?year=2013` the URL rewrites to `http://domain.com/2013/` and it shows the blog (not CPT) posts for that year - it shows the "correct" posts for the URL, but the incorrect posts and URL given the query_vars it was passed.

So the main problem is:
How do I make it rewrite the query_var ?post_type=publications to /publications/, and put it before the /2013/ in the URL?

The secondary problem is:
Why doesn't `http://domain.com/publications/?year=2013` go to `http://domain.com/publications/2013/`? Seems like a canonicalization rule problem??

Thanks.

---

--- original question ---

I have a Custom Post Type, setup using the plugin Types, called Publications.
Pretty permalinks are turned on, and have been re-saved to flush values.

Simple version:
How do I rewrite /?post_type=XXX to /XXX/?

Long version:

When viewing the archive page (archive-publications.php, calling loop-publications.php) the URL correctly re-writes to domain/publications/

My problem is to do with combining years archives.

I have some code in functions.php (rewrite rules) to allow year archives to work - so domain/publications/2013/ shows the posts correctly.

Likewise, domain/?posts_type=publications&year=2013 shows the correct posts, however it rewrites to domain/2013/?posts_type=publications

However domain/publications/?year=2013 rewrites to domain/2013/ and so shows all posts, not just the CPT.

Can you help me make this work "correctly"? I guess I need a new rewrite rule that deals with post_type= and gives it priority over the year rewrite, or something.

Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: Thanks Milo - updated with the functions.php code and a clearer description.

Comment: I think there's a bit of confusion with terminology here. When you say an incoming request "rewrites" to another form, that's not a rewrite, that's a redirection. Rewrite rules have nothing to do with this, all rewrite rules do is tell WordPress how to parse incoming "pretty" requests matching a specific pattern to their component query vars. If you want to fix the redirection of various forms of URLs that aren't the ones you've specifically set up rewrite rules for, you'll have to hook into `parse_request` and set them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Milo. So WordPress redirects query_var like `?post_type=publications` to a pretty permalink like `/publications/` which is then rewritten back to the query_var to display the right content. Is that right?

I'll look at `parse_request` to set a redirect for `post_type=publications`. Cheers.